# Java 8, Hibernate and PostgreSQL - how to store date with timezone?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I use Java 8, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and PostgreSQL. I am considering to store date time with timezone to the database.

I have tried

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created")
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created")
private OffsetDateTime created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created")
private ZonedDateTime created;
```

I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto update` for creating tables, columns, etc. All above mentioned options create column with `timestamp without timezone`. How to create automatically `timestamp with timezone`?

What is the best way to store time and timezone in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally hibernate store dates using UTC. Then you need to convert all time zones into UTC.

On startup,

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ETC/UTC"));
```